# IPv6 Max OS X 10.6 ping fails

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, ip, ipv6, ping

```
$ ifconfig
...
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 00:16:cb:94:1a:79 
inet6 fe80::216:cbff:fe94:1a79%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
inet 192.168.163.200 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 192.168.163.255
media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex,flow-control>)
status: active
...
```

So, as you can see my machine has `fe80::216:cbff:fe94:1a79` address on `en0` interface. Also,

```
$ ping6 fe80::216:cbff:fe94:1a79%en0
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) fe80::216:cbff:fe94:1a79%en0 --> fe80::216:cbff:fe94:1a79%en0
16 bytes from fe80::216:cbff:fe94:1a79%en0, icmp_seq=0 hlim=64 time=0.153 ms
^C
--- fe80::216:cbff:fe94:1a79%en0 ping6 statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/std-dev = 0.153/0.153/0.153/0.000 ms

$
```

But why

```
$ ping6 fe80::216:cbff:fe94:1a79
ping6: UDP connect: No route to host
$
```

fails? Is it possible to access the remote machine without typing an interface name `%en0`?

May be it is a very basic question because I am not a powerful IPv6 user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fe80::` addresses are link-local, that means the address is only unique to that particular adapter.  Each adapter could reference a completely different machine by pinging your provided address `fe80::216:cbff:fe94:1a79`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address